# how to set a four dimension variable in docplex with C#?

Tags: c#, cplex, docplex

how to set a three or four-dimensional variable when calling cplex in C#？

```
using ILOG.Concert;
using ILOG.CPLEX;
```

The following is two -dimensional:

```
INumVar[][] EndTime = new INumVar[NumEMU][];
            for (int i = 0; i < NumEMU; i++)
                EndTime[i] = cplexMod1.NumVarArray(NumJob, 0, 1, NumVarType.Int);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INumVar[][][] x = new INumVar[nb1][][];//creation of i
                for (int i = 0; i < nb2; i++)
                {
                    x[i] = new INumVar[nb2][];//creation of j
                    for (int j = 0; j < nb3; j++)
                    {
                        x[i][j] = new INumVar[nb3];//creation of v
                    }
                }// nb1,nb2,nb3 are integer parameters.
```